# C pointers weird behaviour

Tags: c, pointers

I am having trouble comprehending why this works:

```
int main() {
    int test = 4;
    int *bar = &test;
    int **out = &bar;
    printf("%d\n", **out);
    return 0;
}
```

but this doesn't:

```
void foo(int *src, int **out) {
    out = &src;
}

int main() {
    int test = 4;
    int *bar = &test;
    int **out;
    foo(bar, out);
    printf("%d\n", **out);
    return 0;
}
```

The second snippet throws "Segmentation fault". To me it seems they do the same thing. Can someone explain please?

Edit: (updated code based on answers):

```
void foo(int *src, int **out) {
    out = &src;
}

int main() {
    int test = 4;
    int *bar = &test;
    int *out;
    foo(bar, &out);
    printf("%d\n", *out);
    return 0;
}
```

Then why does this not work?

Solved: (I had to think through what I really wanted to do), this is the result:

```
void foo(int *src, int **out) {
    *out = src;
}

int main() {
    int test = 4;
    int *bar = &test;
    int *out;
    foo(bar, &out);
    printf("%d\n", *out);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: you are affecting the local `int** out` in function not the passed in from main that is the chronic issue of passing by value

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the second, the variable `out` in `main` is not affected by the assignment made inside of `foo`.

In your edit, you need to have `foo` assign to what `out` in it points to:

```
*out = src;
```

Comment: I understand. Can you please my edit, if I am not mistaken now it should work.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I had to sit down and think clearly about what I wanted it to do. Editted in the final code.

Answer (score 0):

Things are passed into functions by value. Changing the value in the function changes nothing in the outside world.